# Adjusting JQuery Code for Image Modals linked to Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have a current modal set-up that uses a jquery script to allow for multiple modals on a single page. Currently, the user selects an image, and that same image pops-up as a modal (event.target). In this instance, I would like users to be able to select a string of text, which pops-up an associated image. I am having difficulty modifying my code to do so. For the sake of clarity, I have placed both instances in a single jsfiddle. Any help would be much appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/csapidus/mh3hysrr/12/

The same code that is in the jsfiddle is below:

```
<title>[BMED] Acrylic Breakdancing Contraption</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4304/35858762401_3288711c9e_o.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Covered+By+Your+Grace|Raleway:100,500,600,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet"> 

<!-- <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

<style>

    * { box-sizing: border-box; }

    /* force scrollbar */
    html { overflow-y: scroll; }

    body { font-family: sans-serif; }

    /* ---- grid ---- */
    .grid {
        background: ;
    }

    /* clear fix */
    .grid:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }

    /* ---- .grid-item ---- */
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
        width: 32.55%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .grid-item {
        float: left;
    }

    .grid-item img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
    }



/******************** Image Modals ********************/

#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 1.0;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }

}
</style> 

<body>

<div class="footerU">
    <h1>[BMED] Acrylic Breakdancing Contraption</h1>
</div>

<div class="intro_unlim">
    <p> The **** final project required students to develop a contraption with at least three connected moving parts. I elected to model a breakdancer's legs as he prepares for a headspin. Unfortunately, the final product came out looking like more of an upside down crab. The legs are made of thin acrylic,  the wood for the base is walnut, and the wood for the body is paduak. </p>

    <p> Estimated Building Cost: $35.00</p>
    <br>
    <p> Clicking this text should open up a modal that presents the first image</p>
    <p> Clicking this text should open up a modal that presents the second image</p>
</div>


    <div class="full">

    <div class="grid">

      <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

      <div class="grid-item">
        <img id="Img1" class = "modal-img" data-index = "1" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4352/36316868716_a33d16e02e_b.jpg"/>
      </div>

      <div id="myModal1" class="modal" data-index="1">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
          <div id="caption">paduak body of the contraption (cut using a jigsaw, and then sanded) nailed to rectangular walnut base</div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item">
        <img id="Img2" class = "modal-img" data-index = "2" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2945/33377180683_9c7b27232f_b.jpg"/>
      </div>

      <div id="myModal2" class="modal" data-index="2">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img02">
          <div id="caption">final product: paduak contraption with acrylic legs, a walnut base, and googley eyes</div>
      </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="return"> 
    <div id="button"><a href="../index.html">Return to Homepage</a></div>
</div>

</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.2.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script>
// JQuery Method for Multiple Modals 
  $(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.modal-img', function(event) {
      var $img = $(event.target);
      var index = $img.data('index');
      var $modal = $("#myModal" + index);
      $modal.find('img').attr('src', $img.attr('src'));
      $modal.find('#caption').text($img.attr('alt'));
      $modal.css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.modal .close', function(event) {
      var $modal = $(event.target).closest('.modal');
      $modal.css('display', 'none');
    });
  });

    // JQuery Method for Masonry
    var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      gutter: 10
    });

    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
      $grid.masonry('layout');
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`See this jsfiddle link that I have created for you: `
```

https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/ubvvesrw/

I am using `$(this)`, I hope this will help you :)